# Focus textbox on flash third party application

Tags: c#, winforms, flash

Is it possible to focus and sent some text in C# from my form to a third party application which is made in flash?

Here is a screenshot of that application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should try with send keys basically sending keystroke on it, take a look at [this SendKeys tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C) for more information .

Basically you need to focus the external app window :

```
int iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, "External App Title");
```

and then use [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) to send keystroke to that :

```
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

Comment: On Windows forms applications works great but seems that on that flash window can't find that textbox to send keys. But the application is great. Let's see if we can find a way to focus that textbox from the flash app.